# Getting key input in a second form not working

Tags: c#, winforms

Hey stackoverflow community. I have a question that I've been trying to figure out for several days now and I was hoping for some help and general advice.

I have been developing a small application. The main form has a few controls some of which open dialog boxes: an `OpenFileDialog`, `SaveFileDialog`, and then a custom dialog for a specific task. The problem arose in the custom dialog box. The basic functionality in a part of the custom dialog box was the ability to click a button that would allow the user to press a key, that key would then be "read" and input into a variable for later use.

My initial thought was to override `WndProc` and have a check for a bool in it, if the bool was true, the data from a `WM_KEYDOWN` message would be stored in a variable and the bool would be set to false. I quickly figured out that doesn't work since Dialog Boxes don't get messages like a normal form does.

My question is what is the best/recommended way to achieve this functionality? I've tried some ad hoc workarounds like just using a regular form and disabling the main form while the second form is active, but that didn't work either and I figured it would be better to ask for advice before I continued.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

### **Edit**

Here is some code to demonstrate my current issue
This has quite a few lines removed since I don't think it would be helpful to post hundreds of lines in here

```
internal class GUI
{
    // This class has all the code for the main form
    // this is one of the Event Handlers that calls the second dialog box
    private static void addItemAbove_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ActionItemDialog aid = new ActionItemDialog();

        if(aid.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ActionList.Items.Insert(list.SelectedIndex, aid.ActionItem);
        }
    }
}

internal class ActionItemDialog : Form
{
    // This class is a custom dialog box for the user to input some data
    private bool keyCaptureOn = false;

    // This event handler is attached to a button on the dialog box
    private void getKey_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getKey.Text = "Press Any Key";
        keyCaptureOn = true;
    }

    // This is the way I was originally trying to get the keypress
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if(m.Msg == 0x100)
        {
            if(keyCaptureOn)
            {
                // have never been able to make it in this.
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);   
    }
}
```

Also it is worthy to note, I have already tried what all the other questions about this have recommended. I've tried setting `KeyPreview` to `true`. I've also made a regular form and used `Form.Show()` and had it emulate a Modal Dialog but I was still never able to get into that second if statement.

Comment: Can you include your code please?

Comment: It's hard to know what you're doing because the post is quite vague about the form that has the "problem" but it's possible by setting [keypreview = true](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview?view=netcore-3.1) that the form can get to know about a keypress before it passes to a control on the form (eg before pressing return clicks the OK button) - is it helpful?

Comment: You need to use an instance of the form.  See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: Just a side comment...`base.WndProc(ref m);` should be OUTSIDE that if statement at the bottom so that all messages you are not interested in would be processed normally.  As written, the form would crash...

Comment: That was a typo, that is where base.WndProc is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ActionItemDialog form, you can add a filter via [IMessageFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter?view=netcore-3.1) to trap keypresses.

When we want to trap a key, we call `filter.trapKey = true;`, which will fire off a custom `Key()` event when the user presses a key.

When the form is dismissed, we remove the filter and event subscription.

Here's an example:

```
public partial class ActionItemDialog : Form
{
    
    private MyFilter filter;

    public ActionItemDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.FormClosing += ActionItemDialog_FormClosing;
        filter = new MyFilter();
        filter.Key += Filter_Key;
        Application.AddMessageFilter(filter);            
    }

    private class MyFilter : IMessageFilter
    {

        public bool trapKey = false;
        public delegate void dlgKey(int key);
        public event dlgKey Key;

        public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
        {
            if (trapKey && m.Msg == 0x100)
            {
                trapKey = false;
                Key?.Invoke((int)m.WParam);                    
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void getKey_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getKey.Text = "Press Any Key";
        filter.trapKey = true;
    }

    private void Filter_Key(int key)
    {
        getKey.Text = key.ToString();
    }

    private void ActionItemDialog_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (filter != null)
        {
            Application.RemoveMessageFilter(filter);
            filter.Key -= Filter_Key;
            filter = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Note that the filter will only trap key presses when YOUR app is in focus (any form of your app).  So if the user clicked to trap a key press, but then switches to another window before pressing the key, then it will not be captured.

To capture a keystroke when ANY application is in focus, you'd have to wire up a low level keyboard hook via WH_KEYBOARD_LL.  This would be overkill since I'd expect the key press to be captured only when that app is in focus.  This could be an alternate approach, though, if you need to trap key presses globally, as registering a hotkey fails if another app already took the combo you want.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for that. I'll see if that works when I get to my PC later today and I'll mark this answer once I confirm